# MongoDb behaviour with multiple urls in connection string

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to understand how mongoDB behaves when connection string contains a few replica urls. Does it try to connect to all replicas or anyone. Does the order in which urls are mentioned matter?

Comment: Connection string *is* a URL. There cannot be "few URLs" in a connection strings.

Answer (score 0):

All writes take place on the primary node. If the primary fails an election takes place where one of the replicas will become primary. Clients can read data from secondaries. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/#replication-in-mongodb